# ROS Navigation: Local costmap doesn't work with custom layer

Tags: navigation, ros, layered

I'm dealing with ros-navigation and its integrated layered costmaps. I have a static map in which obstacles from an occupancy grid need to be inserted. Since Obstacle Layer only can handle specific data (pointclouds from laser scanners etc.) and is apparently not able to handle a occupancy grid as input, I decided to write a **custom layer which takes an occupancy grid** and using the **marking** and **clearing** function from the occupancy grid to add obstacles and/or free space to the master grid. While running, there are **no exceptions** thrown. I figured out that the subscriber successfully receives the occupancy grid and enters the callback which at least runs through to the end. However, the **updateCost**-function (which apparently is responsible to add the modifications to the master grid) **is never called** (the ROS_INFO never throws its message). Therefore, no local map is generated, which causes **RVIZ** to throw a "**No map received**"-warning.

Any ideas of what is wrong with my layer?

The source-code of the **custom layer**:

```
#include<custom_layers/occgrid_to_costmap_layer.h>

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_layer.h>
#include <costmap_2d/layered_costmap.h>
#include <costmap_2d/GenericPluginConfig.h>
#include <costmap_2d/static_layer.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_math.h>
#include <tf2/LinearMath/Transform.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include <map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>
#include <pluginlib/class_list_macros.h>


PLUGINLIB_EXPORT_CLASS(occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace::OTCLayer, costmap_2d::Layer)


using costmap_2d::NO_INFORMATION;
using costmap_2d::LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
using costmap_2d::FREE_SPACE;

namespace occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace
{

    OTCLayer::OTCLayer() : dsrv_(NULL) {}

    OTCLayer::~OTCLayer()
    {
        if (dsrv_){
            delete dsrv_;
        }
    }

    void OTCLayer::onInitialize()
    {
      ros::NodeHandle nh("~/" + name_), g_nh;
      current_ = true;

      global_frame_ = layered_costmap_->getGlobalFrameID();

      nh.param("use_max_value_when_combining", use_max_value_, false);
      nh.param("map_topic", map_topic,  std::string("map"));
      nh.param("marking", marking_, false);
      nh.param("clearing", clearing_, false);

      // Only resubscribe if topic has changed
      if (map_sub_.getTopic() != ros::names::resolve(map_topic))
      {
            // we'll subscribe to the latched topic that the map server uses
            ROS_INFO("Requesting the map from topic %s", map_topic.c_str());
            map_sub_ = g_nh.subscribe(map_topic, 1, &OTCLayer::incomingMap, this);
            map_received_ = false;
            has_updated_data_ = false;

            ros::Rate r(10);
            while (!map_received_ && g_nh.ok())
            {
                ROS_INFO("Waiting for OccGrid...");
                ros::spinOnce();
                r.sleep();
            }

            ROS_INFO("Received a %d X %d map at %f m/pix", getSizeInCellsX(), getSizeInCellsY(), getResolution());

            if (subscribe_to_updates_)
            {
                ROS_INFO("Subscribing to updates");
                map_update_sub_ = g_nh.subscribe(map_topic + "_updates", 10, &OTCLayer::incomingUpdate, this);
            }
      }
      else
      {
            has_updated_data_ = true;
      }

      if (dsrv_)
      {
            delete dsrv_;
      }

      dsrv_ = new dynamic_reconfigure::Server<costmap_2d::GenericPluginConfig>(nh);
      dynamic_reconfigure::Server<costmap_2d::GenericPluginConfig>::CallbackType cb = boost::bind(
          &OTCLayer::reconfigureCB, this, _1, _2);
      dsrv_->setCallback(cb);
    }

    void OTCLayer::reconfigureCB(costmap_2d::GenericPluginConfig &config, uint32_t level)
    {
      if (config.enabled != enabled_)
      {
            enabled_ = config.enabled;
            has_updated_data_ = true;
            x_ = y_ = 0;
            width_ = size_x_;
            height_ = size_y_;
      }
    }

    void OTCLayer::matchSize()
    {
      // If we are using rolling costmap, the static map size is
      //   unrelated to the size of the layered costmap
      if (!layered_costmap_->isRolling())
      {
            Costmap2D* master = layered_costmap_->getCostmap();
            resizeMap(master->getSizeInCellsX(), master->getSizeInCellsY(), master->getResolution(),
                  master->getOriginX(), master->getOriginY());
      }
    }


    void OTCLayer::incomingMap(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGridConstPtr& new_map)
    {
      ROS_INFO("In OTCLayer::incomingMap");
      unsigned int size_x = new_map->info.width, size_y = new_map->info.height;

      ROS_DEBUG("Received a %d X %d map at %f m/pix", size_x, size_y, new_map->info.resolution);

      // resize costmap if size, resolution or origin do not match
      Costmap2D* master = layered_costmap_->getCostmap();
     
      if (size_x_ != size_x || size_y_ != size_y ||
               resolution_ != new_map->info.resolution ||
               origin_x_ != new_map->info.origin.position.x ||
               origin_y_ != new_map->info.origin.position.y)
      {
            // only update the size of the costmap stored locally in this layer
            ROS_INFO("Resizing static layer to %d X %d at %f m/pix", size_x, size_y, new_map->info.resolution);
            resizeMap(size_x, size_y, new_map->info.resolution,
                  new_map->info.origin.position.x, new_map->info.origin.position.y);
      }

      unsigned int index = 0;

      // initialize the costmap with static data
      for (unsigned int i = 0; i < size_y; ++i)
      {
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < size_x; ++j)
            {
            unsigned char value = new_map->data[index];
            if(marking_ && !clearing_ && value!=-1 && value!=0)
            {
                //if only marking = true and value is an obstacle -> set costmap-value to obstacle
                costmap_[index] = LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
            }
            else if(!marking_ && clearing_ && value==0)
                {
                    //if only clearing = true and value is free_space -> set costmap-value to free_space
                costmap_[index] = FREE_SPACE;
            }
            else if(marking_ && clearing_ && value!=-1)
                {
                    //if marking = true and clearing = true and value is not no_information -> set costmap-value to either obstacle or free_space
                if(value==0){
                        costmap_[index] = FREE_SPACE;
                    }
                    else{
                        costmap_[index] = LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
                    }
            }
            ++index;
            }
      }
      map_frame_ = new_map->header.frame_id;

      // we have a new map, update full size of map
      x_ = y_ = 0;
      width_ = size_x_;
      height_ = size_y_;
      map_received_ = true;
      has_updated_data_ = true;
      ROS_INFO("In OTCLayer::incomingMap - finished.");
    }

    void OTCLayer::incomingUpdate(const map_msgs::OccupancyGridUpdateConstPtr& update)
    {
      unsigned int di = 0;
      for (unsigned int y = 0; y < update->height ; y++)
      {
            unsigned int index_base = (update->y + y) * size_x_;
            for (unsigned int x = 0; x < update->width ; x++)
            {
                unsigned int index = index_base + x + update->x;
                unsigned char value = update->data[di++];
                if(marking_ && !clearing_ && value!=-1 && value!=0){
                    //if only marking = true and value is an obstacle -> set costmap-value to obstacle
                    costmap_[index] = LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
                }
                else if(!marking_ && clearing_ && value==0){
                    //if only clearing = true and value is free_space -> set costmap-value to free_space
                    costmap_[index] = FREE_SPACE;
                }
                else if(marking_ && clearing_ && value!=-1){
                    //if marking = true and clearing = true and value is not no_information -> set costmap-value to either obstacle or free_space
                    if(value==0){
                        costmap_[index] = FREE_SPACE;
                    }
                    else{
                        costmap_[index] = LETHAL_OBSTACLE;
                    }
                }
            }
      }
      x_ = update->x;
      y_ = update->y;
      width_ = update->width;
      height_ = update->height;
      has_updated_data_ = true;
    }

    void OTCLayer::activate()
    {
      onInitialize();
    }

    void OTCLayer::deactivate()
    {
      map_sub_.shutdown();
      if (subscribe_to_updates_)
        {
            map_update_sub_.shutdown();
        }
    }

    void OTCLayer::reset()
    {
       onInitialize();
    }

    void OTCLayer::updateBounds(double robot_x, double robot_y, double robot_yaw, double* min_x, double* min_y,
                                   double* max_x, double* max_y)
    {
      if( !layered_costmap_->isRolling() )
        {
            if (!map_received_ || !(has_updated_data_ || has_extra_bounds_))
            {
              ROS_ERROR("IN OTCLayer::updateBounds: FAILED TO RECEIVE MAP!");
              return;
            }
      }
      useExtraBounds(min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y);

      double wx, wy;

      mapToWorld(x_, y_, wx, wy);
      *min_x = std::min(wx, *min_x);
      *min_y = std::min(wy, *min_y);

      mapToWorld(x_ + width_, y_ + height_, wx, wy);
      *max_x = std::max(wx, *max_x);
      *max_y = std::max(wy, *max_y);

      has_updated_data_ = false;
    }

    void OTCLayer::updateCosts(costmap_2d::Costmap2D& master_grid, int min_i, int min_j, int max_i, int max_j)
    {
        ROS_INFO("In OTCLayer::updateCosts");
        if (!map_received_)
        {
            ROS_ERROR("IN OTCLayer::updateCosts: FAILED TO RECEIVE MAP!");
            return;
        }

        if (!enabled_)
        {
            return;
        }
      
        if(use_max_value_)
        {
            ROS_INFO("In OTCLayer::updateCosts - updating master_grid using max_value.");
            updateWithMax(master_grid, min_i, min_j, max_i, max_j);
        }
        else
        {
            ROS_INFO("In OTCLayer::updateCosts - updating master_grid using overwrite.");
            updateWithOverwrite(master_grid, min_i, min_j, max_i, max_j);
        }
    }

}  // namespace occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace
```

The **custom layer's header-file**:

```
#ifndef OCCGRID_TO_COSTMAP_LAYER_H_
#define OCCGRID_TO_COSTMAP_LAYER_H_

#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <costmap_2d/costmap_layer.h>
#include <costmap_2d/layered_costmap.h>
#include <costmap_2d/GenericPluginConfig.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/server.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include <map_msgs/OccupancyGridUpdate.h>
#include <message_filters/subscriber.h>


namespace occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace
{

class OTCLayer : public costmap_2d::CostmapLayer
{
public:
  OTCLayer();
  virtual ~OTCLayer();
  virtual void onInitialize();
  virtual void activate();
  virtual void deactivate();
  virtual void reset();

  virtual void updateBounds(double robot_x, double robot_y, double robot_yaw, double* min_x, double* min_y,
                            double* max_x, double* max_y);
  virtual void updateCosts(costmap_2d::Costmap2D& master_grid, int min_i, int min_j, int max_i, int max_j);

  virtual void matchSize();

private:
  /**
   * @brief  Callback to update the costmap's map from the map_server
   * @param new_map The map to put into the costmap. The origin of the new
   * map along with its size will determine what parts of the costmap's
   * static map are overwritten.
   */
  void incomingMap(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGridConstPtr& new_map);
  void incomingUpdate(const map_msgs::OccupancyGridUpdateConstPtr& update);
  void reconfigureCB(costmap_2d::GenericPluginConfig &config, uint32_t level);

  std::string global_frame_;  ///< @brief The global frame for the costmap
  std::string map_frame_;  /// @brief frame that map is located in
  std::string map_topic;  ///topic where to find the occupancy grid
  bool subscribe_to_updates_;
  bool map_received_;
  bool has_updated_data_;
  bool marking_;
  bool clearing_;
  unsigned int x_, y_, width_, height_;
  bool use_max_value_;
  ros::Subscriber map_sub_, map_update_sub_;

  unsigned char lethal_threshold_, unknown_cost_value_;

  dynamic_reconfigure::Server<costmap_2d::GenericPluginConfig> *dsrv_;
};

}  // namespace occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace

#endif  // OCCGRID_TO_COSTMAP_LAYER.H
```

the **local_costmap_params.yaml**:

```
local_costmap:
  plugins: 
    - {name: occgrid_to_costmap_layer, type: "occgrid_to_costmap_layer_namespace::OTCLayer"}
    - {name: static_layer, type: "costmap_2d::StaticLayer"}
    - {name: inflation_layer, type: "costmap_2d::InflationLayer"}
  track_unknown_space: true
  global_frame: global_costmap_link #according to ros base_local_planner page it should be the same frame as the odometry runs in (/odom atm).
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 10.0 # data comes in
  publish_frequency: 10.0 # costmap publishes info
  rolling_window: true
  recovery_behavior: false
  occgrid_to_costmap_layer:
      map_topic: "test_occ_grid"
  static_layer_path_detection:
      map_topic: "prediction_occ_grid"
      lethal_cost_threshold: 1
```

Note that the code is based on the static_layer-code of costmaps_2D. I tried to remove anything unnecessary but didn't completely understand the full source code, so there might still be unnecessary parts in there (or eventually necessary parts were removed?).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Problem was in the **local_costmap_params.yaml** where I renamed my static layer in the plugin-description as *static_layer* (see on top of the yaml) but declared the map_topic in a therefore non-existing *static_layer_path_detection* namespace. Therefore, the static layer coundn't find a map_topic.

If you run into a similar issue, make sure **all of your plugins in the costmap.yaml are configured properly**! All plugins have to receive their input-data for the layered_costmap-file to call the update_costs-function!

A similar issue can be found [here.](https://answers.ros.org/question/267153/custom-costmap2d-layer-is-not-updating/)